# Selecting the Path objects on multiple Area Types

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I have about 60 "text boxes" (area type objects) and would like to simultaneously adjust their background colors.

This can be done manually by using the Direct Select tool, and shift-clicking the edges of several Area Type objects, then adjusting their fill property.

This workflow is tedious, however, because I can't group these path objects - and thus a single mis-click means I need to redo a lot of meticulous shift-clicking.  Is there a way to explicity select all of these path objects?  Selection -> Object -> same type selects the Area Texts, not their nested path object.

Grumble, thanks for any insight.

Comment: Note, I've also tried saving the selection of directly-selected path objects. When I restored the saved selection, unfortunately it selects the Area Type objects associated with them as well.

Answer (score 0):

Select all Area Type objects, move them to a new Layer, make other layers invisible and then select all the shapes by the Direct Select tool with no shift

Comment: Thank you for the response, but unfortunately this does not work. When I send the Area Type objects to the new layers, the paths/shapes representing the "bounds and background" of the Area Type objects move with them.   I tried the opposite, direct-selecting just the shapes and moving them to their own layer, but the same happens: the Area Type objects move with the shapes.         Basically, it seems that although using direct selection I can manually discriminate between Area Types and their associated shape objects, any batch operations ignore the discrimination.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.. very unintuitive. Here's how:

- Select > Object > All Area Type Objects
- Object > Expand Appearance  (`this was the key step`)

Now the Area Types and their background shapes were 'separated'. Next:

- Select > Object > All Area Type Objects
- Select > Inverse

And now I had all of the shape objects selected, without their Area Types.

I was able to save this selection (via Select > Save Selection), and upon re-choosing this saved selection, only the shapes were selected, not their Area Types.